# I don't know how can I write the below conditions in CPLEX?

Tags: optimization, conditional-statements, cplex

∀ d1, d2 ∈ D: ∃ ( p[i] ∈ P[d1]) ∩(p[j] ∈ P[d2] ) ∩ (l ∈ p[i] ∩ l ∈ p[j])

I want to write this conditions but I don't know how!

I write as you can see, is it correct?

`{int}  path[Demands][K_sp]=...; ( we have k_sp shortest pathes for each demand, that each shortest path includes index of links)
{int}  Path[Demands]=...;  (i insert all of index links for k_sp shortest paths a demand in this array)
forall (i in Demands, j in Demands : i!=j  && card(Path[i] inter Path[j])!=0)
    D[i][j]+D[j][i]==1;`

Answer (score 0):

Could the following help you?

```
{int} D=asSet(1..10);
{int} allP=asSet(1..20);

dvar boolean x[d in D][p in allP]; // for each D , is p in P[d] ?


subject to
{
forall(d1,d2 in D) 1<=sum(p in allP) ((x[d1][p]==1) && (x[d2][p]==1));
}

assert forall(d1,d2 in D) or(p in allP) ((x[d1][p]==1) && (x[d2][p]==1));
```

Comment: thank you, I want to set D[demand_i][demnand_j]=1 and D[demand_j][demnand_i]=0 , when demand i and j have at least one common link. unfortunately, I don't apply a correct condition to the constraint. update some information, if is it possible, I thank you for your considerations

Answer (score 0):

You could use logical constraints:

```
{int} D=asSet(1..10);
{int} allP=asSet(1..20);

dvar boolean x[d in D][p in allP]; // for each D , is p in P[d] ?
dvar boolean DD[d1 in D][d2 in D];

subject to
{
forall(ordered d1,d2 in D) DD[d1][d2]== (1<=sum(p in allP) ((x[d1][p]==1) && (x[d2][p]==1)));
forall(ordered d2,d1 in D) DD[d1][d2]== 1-(1<=sum(p in allP) ((x[d1][p]==1) && (x[d2][p]==1)));
}
```